# Rotate xticks on both seaborn chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a time series data and I plot two charts side by side. I need to rotate x labels as there are too may years to show. When I add `plt.xticks(rotation=45)` it changes rotation only for the second plot but not the first. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
values = range(0,120)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2000', end='2010', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,
                     'value':values})

def box_plot(df, value):
    # Prepare data
    data_date = df.reset_index()
    data_date['year'] = [d.year for d in data_date.Date]
    data_date['month'] = [d.strftime('%b') for d in data_date.Date]
    years = data_date['year'].unique()

    # Draw Plot
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,7), dpi= 80)
    sns.boxplot(x='year', y=value, data=data_date, ax=axes[0])    
    sns.boxplot(x='month', y=value, data=data_date)

    # Set Title
    axes[0].set_title('Year-wise Box Plot '+value+'\n(The Trend)', fontsize=18); 
    axes[1].set_title('Month-wise Box Plot '+value+'\n(The Seasonality)', fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params()` method instead of `plt.xticks`. The latter only applies to the 'current', in this case most recently generated, axes instance while the former can be used on any axes instance. For example:

```py
axes[0].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
axes[1].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```